# No battery - 1% remaining

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

I've recently installed cm11 (plain CyanogenMod) and the battery indicator showed 1% after a full charge and would not budge.  I decided, 10 minutes later, to wipe and go to another ROM, maybe try a new one.  I did so, changing everything including the kernel - and the battery stays the same at 1%.  The only thing I have not tried is leaving the phone to die, <strike>giving it a funeral and a tombstone</strike> and doing the "charge trick" but I've heard it's also a myth.  Can somebody please help me avoid a broken phone?

And also, just in case: Phone model is ST18i Xperia Ray.  Warranty voided due to rooting :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Itzik Samara's answer is all you need. But I thought I'd add some information for people without CWM or with a version that can't delete the Battery Stats for some reason (as you had this concern initially yourself).

This can also be done less elegantly via [adb](/questions/tagged/adb)

Firstly ensure your device is **FULLY CHARGED**. **Do not do the below without charging fully!**

1. Reboot your phone into recovery.
2. Mount /system and /data in the partitions menu.
3. Open up a cmd prompt:

   adb pull /data/system/batterystats.bin batterystats.bin

   This command save the batterystats.bin in the same directory as your adb.
4. Run:

   adb shell
5. And finally:

rm /data/system/batterystats.bin

This removes the entire battery stats file from the device. It will be rebuilt on reboot.

Comment: Thank you.  This has solved my problem with not being able to erase the Battery Stats via CWM.

Comment: @xezno glad to hear it :) Please consider an upvote if this has helped.

Comment: Lol I don't have 15 reputation, does it not count my stackexchange reputation? damn

Comment: Ah not to worry, and no you start again from scratch. If you have enough rep when you join a new exchange site you get 101 to start with as 'we trust you'. Doesn't matter anyway, glad to help anyone that it does help! :)

Comment: Ah okay, when I get 15 rep I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

Try Those Steps

```
How to wipe Battery Stats?
1. charging the battery FULLY (Since you dont know just charge it for a day and half to make sure its full)
2. boot device to CWM Recovery
3. advanced/Wipe Battery Stats
4. reboot device
5. don't charge the device until the battery still turns off your device because it empty (do not drain with heavy apps like video streaming ect.)
6. now again FULLY charge without interruption
7. Have fun ^^
```

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1517044)

Comment: I'm trying this now, but I'm unsure if I have Wipe Battery Stats in my CWM Recovery.  Is there a certain version I need?

Comment: +1 this is the easiest way to do this. I have posted an answer for the unlikely case that CWM doesn't do this for you, or you don't have a recovery that supports the option.